# Resetting app data setting using background worker in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building a WP7 app. I want to reset my app data settings at a given time. I have tried resetting by comparing the hour of the given time and "`DateTime.Now.Hour`" when the Main Page loads(i.e. when I open the app at the given time). But if I open the app after the given time, it doesn't reset at all. So, I want to know if there is any way to solve this. I haven't used Background Worker before but I think it can help. Can somebody suggest me a way out of it?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run apps permanently in the background on Windows Phone. When your app launches or is activated you should check if the delete time has passed (`DateTime.Now > deleteTime`).

You could consider using a background agent that can run every 30 mins, but beware the limitations especially on 256MB devices.